# outline behaviour while focus on click and focus on tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I got CSS or jQuery/JavaScript question.

I set on many elements tabindex="0" because I need to provide tabbing through page, but I'm wondering why on pages like stackoverflow.com or developer.mozilla.org when I click by mouse I can't see outline on focus, but on my page when I click by mouse I can see outline.

Are they really setting some jQuery/JS preventing showing outline or maybe there is some good way of setting outline in css to prevent showing it?

Edit: 
1. Elements on my page should have outline when user is tabbing through page by tab key, 
2. Elements on my page should not have outline when user is clicking on elements by mouse

Comment: It's a CSS rule: `outline: 0`

Comment: no, it's not just outline: 0, because I want to have outline on key press, and I don't want it on mouse click

Comment: I meant that's what stackoverflow are using.

Comment: how you find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use

```
 input,button,textarea,-----{
  outline: 0; //or outline: none;
  }   (OR)
 // Create One Class With Above Property ,Give That Class To Particular Html Element Like Below ,
.className{
  outline: 0; //or outline: none;
  }
```